# How to get kvm real CPU usage percent in libvirt?

Tags: openstack, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I can get the qemu cpu usage in the host. But it's absolute usage.

I want to get the relative cpu usage percent like the inner the vm, it's "80%", but in the host it only used 30%,

how can I get the "80%" ?

I tried to read proc/stat, but it's not a real file so can't.

And is there a universal method to get in both Linux and Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `ceilometer` measurements `cpu_util`?